# Ubuntu 18.04: Gnome lock screen refuse correct password

Tags: gnome, 18.04, login, password, lock-screen

Gnome lock screen refuse my correct password. I need to reboot every time, when I get into lock screen.

I upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04. I have Russian and English layouts (maybe it's the root of problem...)

I read about 10 similar questions. I have made all commands via terminal like a

```
sudo chown root:shadow /etc/gshadow
sudo chown root:shadow /etc/gshadow-
sudo chown root:shadow /etc/shadow
sudo chown root:shadow /etc/shadow
```

But it didn't help. I am not programmer I just want to work on my computer but I can't.

Answer (score 5):

I have the same issue and tried a lot of solutions offered around the internet. So far, the only work around that worked when this happens:

1. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> - switch to a different console and login as your user
2. `sudo killall gnome-screensaver` - to kill the screensaver
3. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> - switch back to your X screen, there will no longer be a screensaver
4. `gnome-screensaver-command -l` to lock your screen again and now unlock with your password (it should work now)

Note that if I don't do #4, the screen continue to go blank after a few minutes of being logged in, which is why I figured I needed to do #4.

**Edit from 2020**: Yet another alternative, inspired by EChip's answer: setup a cron script that will switch language back to English when the screen lock dialog is detected:

```
# Allows to avoid situation when on screen lock language other than
# English is selected.
#
# Set up under user's cron like this:
# * * * * * env DISPLAY=:0 /bin/bash /storage/scripts/unlock_helper.sh > /home/your_user_name/log.txt 2>&1
#
# Prerequisite:
# Add the following line to you .profile:
#    set | grep DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS > ~/.DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS

source /home/your_user_name/.DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
echo $DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS

if (/usr/bin/gnome-screensaver-command -q | /bin/grep "is active");
then
    /usr/bin/gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell \
        --object-path /org/gnome/Shell \
        --method org.gnome.Shell.Eval \
        "imports.ui.status.keyboard.getInputSourceManager().inputSources[0].activate()"
fi
```

Comment: I'm not positive but this sounds like the hotkey combinations for Ubuntu 16.04 not 18.04.

Comment: This combination wilk work for both versions.

Comment: In: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BionicBeaver/ReleaseNotes it says: ***"The login screen now uses virtual terminal 1 instead of virtual terminal 7. "***

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I won't claim that the release notes are wrong but I just confirmed I have 18.04.1 LTS and X still runs on 7. Mine is a relatively new install without customizations as far as I recall

Comment: While `sudo killall gnome-screensaver` release the lock, `gnome-screensaver-command -l` did not relock the screen in ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS. Now I have no lock screen.

Comment: When I execute the command "sudo killall gnome-screensaver", it tell me that: "no gnome-screensaver process". Why this happens? Do you have other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

My alternative is to remove screensavers(gnome-screensaver, xscreensaver) at all.

I can not do remember every time when I lock pc to switch layout to US.
The punishment here is incorrect password error in lock screen of screensavers.

**Steps** to lock screen with Super+L without screensaver but with login screen:
**1.** sudo apt-get remove xscreensaver
**2.** Remove xscreensaver from startup applications, if you add it before
**3.** Go to ***Settings>Devices>Keyboard*** and disable standart command (Super+L)
**4.** Create new custom shortcut (Super+L) for command

```
dm-tool switch-to-greeter
```

I am almost happy now

UPD:
To turn off display, we can use command:

```
xset dpms force off
```

So now to pack "switch-to-greeter" and "display off" into one shell script and link it to the "Super+L" is not a big question