# How to automatically switch keyboard layout to English on screen lock?

Tags: gnome, login, keyboard-layout, lock-screen

I'd like my Ubuntu to automatically switch my keyboard layout to English each time I lock the screen, so that I wouldn't have to do it manually each time to enter my password. How do I do that?

Also, I'd like that my keyboard layout also be English each time after I unlock the screen. Is it possible?

Comment: you can make a script with below content like `gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell --object-path /org/gnome/Shell --method org.gnome.Shell.Eval "imports.ui.status.keyboard.getInputSourceManager().inputSources[1].activate()" && gnome-screensaver-command -l &` and make a keyboard shortcut to run that script. change inputSources[1] with your languages list starting from 0

Comment: Does this answer solve your problem: [Ubuntu 18.04: Gnome lock screen refuse correct password](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1070774/ubuntu-18-04-gnome-lock-screen-refuse-correct-password)?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat in Xubuntu did you install GNOME? is your distribution Xubuntu have GNOME and GDM? if yes can you provide the gnome-shell version?

Comment: @UnKNOWn I'm using the stock Xubuntu 22.04 (so, lightgdm).

Comment: Maybe this thread can help you find an answer: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/LightDM#Wrong_locale_displayed

Comment: @starkus I don't think that's it. Locale probably defines the interface language, not the input language.

Answer (score 0):

Just bumped into the same problem, use xkblayout-state tool like this (assuming 0 is the default En keyboard layout)

```
xkblayout-state set 0
```

then you can first change the keyboard layout to the default and launch
screenlocker like this

```
 xkblayout-state set 0 && screen_locker
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to dive into command line, you can configure keyboard layout switcher to remember layout for each window. As the lock screen has it's own window, it will use the first keyboard layout regardless of which language you were typing before.

In KDE: System Settings -> Input devices -> Keyboard -> Layouts -> set `Switching Policy` to `Window`.
You will also need to set your first layout to English.

Answer (score 0):

Since `xkb` tools do not work on Wayland, I wrote an extension that solves the problem by automatically resetting keyboard layout when screensaver activates. You can get extension here: https://github.com/galets/gnome-keyboard-reset