# 'gnome-screensaver-command -l' does not work as well as super+L on Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

Tags: gnome, lock-screen, screensaver

I have had some trouble with logging on in the lock screen (apparently something to do with keyboard language). On the process of debugging, I was following @0x4B1D answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1070774/ubuntu-18-04-gnome-lock-screen-refuse-correct-password). The fourth step does nothing for me.

Now, neither <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd> locks nor `gnome-screensaver-command -l`.

`gnome-screensaver-command -a` does raise a blank screen, though no password is needed.

I have tried rebooting and reinstalling gnome and I do not want to go to any other screensaver methods such as `xscreensaver`.

I am far from being an expert on Ubuntu. How do I even begin to cope with this?

Answer (score 0):

You may use the native way of sending a message to a D-Bus message bus. Run the following command to invoke the screen-lock:

```
dbus-send --type=method_call --dest=org.gnome.ScreenSaver /org/gnome/ScreenSaver org.gnome.ScreenSaver.Lock
```

Comment: That did nothing. Nither did it lock the pc nor did it enable locking.

Comment: That sounds strange indeed. Do you find something noticeable in the logs while trying to activate the lock screen in various ways?

Comment: I have no idea what to look for or where are the logs.

Answer (score 0):

(I'm running gdm3 on ubuntu 20.04).

Check the value of the disable-lock-screen setting, as it seems to interact with (cause to fail) everything else that would ever like to lock the screen. From the command line:

```bash
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen
```

When the setting is `true`, nothing will make the screen lock for me.  (Including, not even the dbus-send command suggested above).  I find that I also have no lock icon in my desktop taskbar far-right drop-down menu (where power-off is found).

If you change the setting to `false`, the lock-icon comes back when that menu is dropped-down. Again, from the command line:

```bash
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen  false
```

And then I can lock in any of the usual ways, including by clicking that newly reappeared lock-icon, or using keyboard shortcut (<kbd>super</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd>), or setting up the ubuntu-lock-on-suspend timeout mechanism, or the dbus-send command suggested by pomsky (above), or this from the command line:

```bash
DISPLAY=:0  gnome-screensaver-command -l
```